# No Suspend possible after videocard upgrade, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, xorg, suspend, wayland

Ubuntu 22.04.

Replaced NVidia GTX 1660 to AMD 6700 XT. Installed correct drivers and removed old nvidia drivers. After that if I press "suspend" than it tries to do it, my display goes shortly black and a couple of seconds later login screen appears, it can not suspend. First I've used wayland, but as it was not possible to see current keyboard layout there, I have switched to Xorg. Suspend does not work in Wayland as well.

Also I have noticed that my USB WebCam with a LED is after upgrade "always on", the LED can not be switched off even if the cam is not in use.

If I boot Ubuntu 22.04 from my USB stick than everything works as it should. So the problem exists only after upgrade. What am I missing and which things should I reconfigure?

I have also tried to install pm-utils and I even can suspend with it, but it freezes after wake-up.

I attach a "journalctl  --follow" after pressing suspend button

**glxinfo | grep -iE 'vendor:|device:|version:'**

```
GLX version: 1.4**
     Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
     Device: AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT (navi22, LLVM 15.0.3, DRM 3.48, 5.18.1-051801-generic) (0x73df)
     Version: 22.3.0
     Max core profile version: 4.6
     Max compat profile version: 4.6
     Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
     Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
```

**Suspend logs**

```
Apr 17 16:59:27 ubuntoid audit[67994]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:27 ubuntoid kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1681743567.964:285): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0





Apr 17 16:59:32 ubuntoid audit[67994]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:32 ubuntoid kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1681743572.964:286): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.6832] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.6833] device (enp39s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid ModemManager[1169]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.6917] device (p2p-dev-wlp37s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.6919] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.6920] device (wlp37s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[1101]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=0 pid=1103 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Timelines with detached actors are not supported. <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_panel_AggregateMenu>:0x558675d9a0c0] in animation of duration 150ms but not on stage.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[1101]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid kernel: wlp37s0: deauthenticating from cc:ce:1e:a4:63:ef by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=cc:ce:1e:a4:63:ef reason=3 locally_generated=1
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.8918] device (wlp37s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.8919] device (wlp37s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.9151] dhcp4 (wlp37s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.9151] dhcp4 (wlp37s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.9151] dhcp4 (wlp37s0): state changed no lease
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid avahi-daemon[1097]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.26 on wlp37s0.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid avahi-daemon[1097]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp37s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.26.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid systemd-resolved[973]: wlp37s0: Bus client reset search domain list.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid avahi-daemon[1097]: Interface wlp37s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid systemd-resolved[973]: wlp37s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid systemd-resolved[973]: wlp37s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Apr 17 16:59:35 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743575.9557] device (wlp37s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid gsd-media-keys[4423]: Unable to get default sink
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.025][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:34][info] Updating screens due to notification
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:46][info] Screens changed from ( 1 ):
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:42][info] - 0 QRect(0,0 3840x2160) QRect(92,54 3748x2106) (primary)
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:48][info] to ( 1 ):
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:42][info] - 0 QRect(0,0 3840x2160) QRect(0,54 3840x2106) (primary)
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:36.026][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: p2p-dev-wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: p2p-dev-wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp37s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: wlp37s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid wpa_supplicant[1126]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp37s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid rtkit-daemon[1341]: Supervising 12 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid rtkit-daemon[1341]: Successfully made thread 69975 of process 4062 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Apr 17 16:59:36 ubuntoid rtkit-daemon[1341]: Supervising 13 threads of 8 processes of 1 users.
Apr 17 16:59:37 ubuntoid audit[67994]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:37 ubuntoid kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1681743577.964:287): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[1101]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.99' (uid=1000 pid=4300 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid fprintd[70004]: Failed to install a sleep delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[1101]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Apr 17 16:59:41 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
                                            asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23
Apr 17 16:59:42 ubuntoid audit[67994]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:42 ubuntoid kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1681743582.964:288): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kreya.kreya" name="/proc/zoneinfo" pid=67994 comm="PressureMonitor" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Apr 17 16:59:44 ubuntoid gdm-password][70007]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Apr 17 16:59:44 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[4066]: [session uid=1000 pid=4066] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1000 pid=4300 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")
Apr 17 16:59:44 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[4066]: [session uid=1000 pid=4066] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Apr 17 16:59:44 ubuntoid NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681743584.9794] agent-manager: agent[f6e914955449dc58,:1.99/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[4300]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[4300]: unable to update icon for livepatch
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[4300]: unable to update icon for Sticky Notes
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[4066]: [session uid=1000 pid=4066] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.150' (uid=1000 pid=70029 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters")
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid dbus-daemon[4066]: [session uid=1000 pid=4066] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:34][info] Updating screens due to notification
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:46][info] Screens changed from ( 1 ):
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:42][info] - 0 QRect(0,0 3840x2160) QRect(0,54 3840x2106) (primary)
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:48][info] to ( 1 ):
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/platformscreens.cpp:42][info] - 0 QRect(0,0 3840x2160) QRect(92,54 3748x2106) (primary)
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid pia-client.desktop[4516]: [2023-04-17 14:59:45.208][6fed][default][client/src/workspacechange.cpp:16][info] Workspace changed
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x558674b22300] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x558676b5c760] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55867bfbd860] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55867bf83b00] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55867bfbd160] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55867bf82f30] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55867bfbca60] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x55867bf82b40] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x558676cf7bd0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Apr 17 16:59:45 ubuntoid gnome-shell[4300]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Apr 17 16:59:46 ubuntoid systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Comment: It may be helpful from a diagnostic standpoint to unplug any non essential devices (for example, your webcam), then reboot, then try to suspend again. This will aid in fact finding because you can all but eliminate these devices as the problem by using process of elimination. It's concerning that you have other problems that seem unrelated to suspend. FYI, it's best practice to reinstall the OS with a major hardware change and switching the GPU from Nvidia to AMD is definitely a major hardware change. You may need to reinstall the OS if the "shortcut" method didn't work.

Comment: My webcam is usually unplugged, the logs above are without webcam attached. And I do not have any other devices, just a mic. Even monitor USB hub is not in use. Internally I have a couple of old SATA SSDs and one m.2 SSD. Should I add more configuration info?